# makefile dependent has no effect

Tags: gcc, makefile

Here is my directory tree:

```
tree ./
./
├── common
│   └── common.h
├── dir1
│   ├── a1.c
│   ├── a1.h
│   ├── b1.c
│   ├── b1.h
│   ├── c1.c
│   ├── c1.h
│   └── dir1.mk
├── makefile
└── sys-make
    ├── gcc.mk
    └── rules.mk
```

each c file include it's own header file and common header, says `a1.c` includes `a1.h` and `common.h`. I have mainly 4 makediles:

makefile:

```
TOP_DIR = $(PWD)
MKFILE_DIR = $(TOP_DIR)/sys-make
OUTPUT_DIR = $(TOP_DIR)/output

export TOP_DIR MKFILE_DIR 

all:
    @echo "$(PWD)/makefile"
    @echo "$(CC_DEFS)"
    @$(MAKE) -f $(TOP_DIR)/dir1/dir1.mk


clean:
    @$(MAKE) -f $(TOP_DIR)/dir1/dir1.mk clean
```

dir1.mk:

```
MODULE = dir1

MOD_LIB = ./lib$(MODULE).a

SRC_FILES =
SRC_FILES += a1.c
SRC_FILES += b1.c
SRC_FILES += c1.c

INC_PATH =
INC_PATH += $(TOP_DIR)/common

SRC_PATH =
SRC_PATH += $(TOP_DIR)/dir1
SRC_PATH += $(TOP_DIR)/dir1/sub_dir1

vpath %.c $(SRC_PATH)

include $(MKFILE_DIR)/gcc.mk
include $(MKFILE_DIR)/rules.mk
```

gcc.mk

```
CC :=
CC = gcc

CFLAG :=
CFLAG = -ggdb -Wall
```

rules.mk

```
OUTPUT_DIR = $(TOP_DIR)/output/$(MODULE)
OBJS = $(addprefix $(OUTPUT_DIR)/,$(SRC_FILES:.c=.o))
DEPS = $(addprefix $(OUTPUT_DIR)/,$(SRC_FILES:.c=.d))

$(OUTPUT_DIR)/$(MOD_LIB): $(OBJS)
    @ar cr $@ $^
    @echo "ar $@"

$(OUTPUT_DIR)/%.o: %.c
    @echo "objs: $(OBJS)"
    @echo "deps: $(DEPS)"
    @echo "outs: $(OUTPUT_DIR)"
    @mkdir -p $(OUTPUT_DIR)
    $(CC) $(CFLAG) $(CC_DEFS) -I$(INC_PATH) -MM -MF  $(patsubst %.o,%.d,$@) -o $@ $< 
    @echo "cc $(notdir $<)"

clean:
    -@rm -r $(OUTPUT_DIR)

-include $(DEPS)
```

after first compile, no problem and `*.o`, `*.d` and `*.a` are generated to `./output/dir1`. the problem is, no matter I touch `*1.h` or `common.h`, it always shows:

```
make[1]: `/home/haochen/Work/test_code/test_makefile/output/dir1/./libdir1.a' is up to date.
```

Seems my depends file has problem, when I cat `a.d`, it shows:

```
cat output/dir1/a1.d
a1.o: /home/haochen/Work/test_code/test_makefile/dir1/a1.c \
 /home/haochen/Work/test_code/test_makefile/dir1/a1.h \
 /home/haochen/Work/test_code/test_makefile/common/common.h
```

any problem in my makefile? I try to replace `-MM -MF  $(patsubst %.o,%.d,$@)` with `-MMD`, but output like:

```
make                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
/home/haochen/Work/test_code/test_makefile/makefile
SYS1 SYS2 SYS3 SYS4
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/haochen/Work/test_code/test_makefile'
objs: /home/haochen/Work/test_code/test_makefile/output/dir1/a1.o /home/haochen/Work/test_code/test_makefile/output/dir1/b1.o /home/haochen/Work/test_code/test_makefile/output/dir1/c1.o
deps: /home/haochen/Work/test_code/test_makefile/output/dir1/a1.d /home/haochen/Work/test_code/test_makefile/output/dir1/b1.d /home/haochen/Work/test_code/test_makefile/output/dir1/c1.d
outs: /home/haochen/Work/test_code/test_makefile/output/dir1
gcc -ggdb -Wall  -I /home/haochen/Work/test_code/test_makefile/common -MMD -o /home/haochen/Work/test_code/test_makefile/output/dir1/a1.o /home/haochen/Work/test_code/test_makefile/dir1/a1.c
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 0 has invalid symbol index 11
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 1 has invalid symbol index 12
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 2 has invalid symbol index 2
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 3 has invalid symbol index 2
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 4 has invalid symbol index 11
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 5 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 6 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 7 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 8 has invalid symbol index 12
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 9 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 10 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 11 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 12 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 13 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 14 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 15 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 16 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 17 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 18 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 19 has invalid symbol index 21
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_line): relocation 0 has invalid symbol index 2
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [/home/haochen/Work/test_code/test_makefile/output/dir1/a1.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/haochen/Work/test_code/test_makefile'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Try replacing `-MM -MF  $(patsubst %.o,%.d,$@)` with `-MMD`.

Comment: @user657267 , where I should put my dependent? At the bottom or before targets?

Comment: Sorry i don't understand, you need to replace the entire section i quoted above with just `-MMD`.

Comment: @user657267 , I mean if my `-include $(DEPS)` possition is correct? I try your suggestion, error ourput, I updated in my question

Comment: It may help you to call `make --debug=v` to detect where the dependencies are broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the problem in the output of the `.d` file that you show:

```
a1.o: /home/haochen/Work/test_code/test_makefile/dir1/a1.c \
```

The target here is `a1.o`.  However, the target you're actually building is `$(OUTPUT_DIR)/a1.o`.  So, make doesn't apply these extra prerequisites to that target and so it doesn't check them to see if they've changed when building that target.

You need the target name to be the exact target you're building: you can use the `-MT` option for that.  For example:

```
$(OUTPUT_DIR)/%.o: %.c
        @mkdir -p $(OUTPUT_DIR)
        $(CC) $(CFLAG) $(CC_DEFS) -I$(INC_PATH) -MM -MF $(patsubst %.o,%.d,$@) -MT $@ -o $@ $< 
        @echo "cc $(notdir $<)"
```

Comment: it solved problem, but I found the generated `*.o` is empty use above command. I did a test to use `gcc -o ./a1.o ./a1.c` , I can generate correct object file, any comment?

Comment: I use `$(CC) $(CFLAG) $(CC_DEFS) -I$(INC_PATH) -MMD -c $< -o $@
`, seems problem fixed